# Android Native Lib Crash

Tags: android, crash, native

I am getting a huge number of below crashes in the Playstore console with limited stacktrace only.

[image]

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000021f6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
  #01  pc 00000000000080d8  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+304)
  #02  pc 000000000000f0f8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::sp_report_race()+28)
  #03  pc 0000000000115324  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::RootRenderNode::detachAnimators()+316)
  #04  pc 0000000000113434  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AnimationContextBridge::destroy()+24)
  #05  pc 000000000049e99c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::destroy()+128)
  #06  pc 00000000004a2780  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (std::__1::packaged_task<void ()>::operator()()+88)
  #07  pc 000000000045971c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+168)
  #08  pc 000000000011fb30  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+240)
  #09  pc 000000000000f9d4  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
  #10  pc 00000000000836c8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+196)
  #11  pc 0000000000023bac  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Could someone already reproduce the issue or at least explain when the issue occurs and how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Same issue

```
Device: Samsung Galaxy A8(2018)
Operating System: Android 9 (SDK 28)
Rooted: No
ABI: arm64-v8a

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.rdiscovery <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000021ef4  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
  #00  pc 00000000000080d8  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+304)
  #00  pc 0000000000108c40  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_view_RenderNode_hasIdentityMatrix(long)+116)
  #00  pc 0000000000429e20  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x41f000) (android.graphics.Matrix.nIsAffine [DEDUPED]+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000bfabc0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x41f000) (android.view.RenderNode.hasIdentityMatrix+48)
  #00  pc 0000000000cee608  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x41f000) (android.view.View.transformFromViewToWindowSpace+440)
  #00  pc 0000000000cd68cc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x41f000) (android.view.View.getLocationInWindow+76)
  #00  pc 0000000000cd6990  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x41f000) (android.view.View.getLocationOnScreen+48)
  #00  pc 000000000003b5e4  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_6979_6979 (deleted)
```

Comment: It was happening for me because some of the view renderings weren't lifecycle aware.